# Upload to Amazon S3 through the API

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, google-chrome-extension

I'm in the process of developing a Chrome Extension, and I want to upload some files through the extension to my Amazon S3 Bucket. However, I cannot use the AWS SDK because extensions don't allow libraries. Is there some way to upload a javascript file/text file by using an API instead?

I have an Amazon S3 Bucket and CloudFront already active. I would prefer not to use the Amazon API Gateway if possible as it is free only for the first month.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: what programming language are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I never come across the S3 feature to upload objects without the libraries except **Presigned URL**
2. But, to generate presigned URL, you need S3 libraries.
3. Either go through the API Gateway completely. or
4. Expose an API to generate and retrieve the presigned URL. Once you receive the presigned URL, you can upload the object with the simple HTTP request.